# Adding Argument to a char device

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, device-driver

I am writing a character device that will be given a processes pid and return the parent process id, start time, and number of siblings. I am using this site: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x892.html#AEN972 as a guide. 
I would like to add an argument into the read call of the character driver but it is not letting me do that. My code looks like this:

```
   /*
 *  chardev.c - Create an input/output character device
 */

#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* We're doing kernel work */
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Specifically, a module */
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>    /* for get_user and put_user */

#include "chardev.h"
#define SUCCESS 0
#define DEVICE_NAME "char_dev"
#define BUF_LEN 80
struct procinfo { 
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t ppid;
    struct timespec start_time;
    int num_sib;
};

/* 
 * Is the device open right now? Used to prevent
 * concurent access into the same device 
 */
static int Device_Open = 0;

/* 
 * The message the device will give when asked 
 */
static char Message[BUF_LEN];

/* 
 * How far did the process reading the message get?
 * Useful if the message is larger than the size of the
 * buffer we get to fill in device_read. 
 */
static char *Message_Ptr;

/* 
 * This is called whenever a process attempts to open the device file 
 */
static int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "device_open(%p)\n", file);
#endif

    /* 
     * We don't want to talk to two processes at the same time 
     */
    if (Device_Open)
        return -EBUSY;

    Device_Open++;
    /*
     * Initialize the message 
     */
    Message_Ptr = Message;
    try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);
    return SUCCESS;
}

static int device_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "device_release(%p,%p)\n", inode, file);
#endif

    /* 
     * We're now ready for our next caller 
     */
    Device_Open--;

    module_put(THIS_MODULE);
    return SUCCESS;
}

/* 
 * This function is called whenever a process which has already opened the
 * device file attempts to read from it.
 */
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *file,   /* see include/linux/fs.h   */
               char __user * buffer,    /* buffer to be
                             * filled with data */
                           pid_t pid,
               size_t length,   /* length of the buffer     */
               loff_t * offset)
{
    /* 
     * Number of bytes actually written to the buffer 
     */
    int bytes_read = 0;

#ifdef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "device_read(%p,%p,%d)\n", file, buffer, length);
#endif

    /* 
     * If we're at the end of the message, return 0
     * (which signifies end of file) 
     */
    if (*Message_Ptr == 0)
        return 0;

    /* 
     * Actually put the data into the buffer 
     */
    while (length && *Message_Ptr) {

        /* 
         * Because the buffer is in the user data segment,
         * not the kernel data segment, assignment wouldn't
         * work. Instead, we have to use put_user which
         * copies data from the kernel data segment to the
         * user data segment. 
         */
        put_user(*(Message_Ptr++), buffer++);
        length--;
        bytes_read++;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "Read %d bytes, %d left\n", bytes_read, length);
#endif

    /* 
     * Read functions are supposed to return the number
     * of bytes actually inserted into the buffer 
     */
    return bytes_read;
}

/* 
 * This function is called when somebody tries to
 * write into our device file. 
 */
static ssize_t
device_write(struct file *file,
         const char __user * buffer, size_t length, loff_t * offset)
{
    int i;

#ifdef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "device_write(%p,%s,%d)", file, buffer, length);
#endif

    for (i = 0; i < length && i < BUF_LEN; i++)
        get_user(Message[i], buffer + i);

    Message_Ptr = Message;

    /* 
     * Again, return the number of input characters used 
     */
    return i;
}

/* 
 * This function is called whenever a process tries to do an ioctl on our
 * device file. We get two extra parameters (additional to the inode and file
 * structures, which all device functions get): the number of the ioctl called
 * and the parameter given to the ioctl function.
 *
 * If the ioctl is write or read/write (meaning output is returned to the
 * calling process), the ioctl call returns the output of this function.
 *
 */
long device_ioctl(struct file *file,    /* see include/linux/fs.h */
                  unsigned int ioctl_num,   /* number and param for ioctl */
                  unsigned long ioctl_param)
{
    int i;
    char *temp;
    char ch;

    /* 
     * Switch according to the ioctl called 
     */
    switch (ioctl_num) {
    case IOCTL_SET_MSG:
        /* 
         * Receive a pointer to a message (in user space) and set that
         * to be the device's message.  Get the parameter given to 
         * ioctl by the process. 
         */
        temp = (char *)ioctl_param;

        /* 
         * Find the length of the message 
         */
        get_user(ch, temp);
        for (i = 0; ch && i < BUF_LEN; i++, temp++)
            get_user(ch, temp);

        device_write(file, (char *)ioctl_param, i, 0);
        break;

    case IOCTL_GET_MSG:
        /* 
         * Give the current message to the calling process - 
         * the parameter we got is a pointer, fill it. 
         */
        i = device_read(file, (char *)ioctl_param, 99, 0);

        /* 
         * Put a zero at the end of the buffer, so it will be 
         * properly terminated 
         */
        put_user('\0', (char *)ioctl_param + i);
        break;

    case IOCTL_GET_NTH_BYTE:
        /* 
         * This ioctl is both input (ioctl_param) and 
         * output (the return value of this function) 
         */
        return Message[ioctl_param];
        break;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

/* Module Declarations */

/* 
 * This structure will hold the functions to be called
 * when a process does something to the device we
 * created. Since a pointer to this structure is kept in
 * the devices table, it can't be local to
 * init_module. NULL is for unimplemented functions. 
 */
struct file_operations Fops = {
    .read = device_read,
    .write = device_write,
    .unlocked_ioctl = device_ioctl,
    .open = device_open,
    .release = device_release,  /* a.k.a. close */
};

/* 
 * Initialize the module - Register the character device 
 */
int init_module()
{
    int ret_val;
    /* 
     * Register the character device (atleast try) 
     */
    ret_val = register_chrdev(MAJOR_NUM, DEVICE_NAME, &Fops);

    /* 
     * Negative values signify an error 
     */
    if (ret_val < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s failed with %d\n",
               "Sorry, registering the character device ", ret_val);
        return ret_val;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "%s The major device number is %d.\n",
           "Registeration is a success", MAJOR_NUM);
    printk(KERN_INFO "If you want to talk to the device driver,\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "you'll have to create a device file. \n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "We suggest you use:\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "mknod %s c %d 0\n", DEVICE_FILE_NAME, MAJOR_NUM);
    printk(KERN_INFO "The device file name is important, because\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "the ioctl program assumes that's the\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "file you'll use.\n");

    return 0;
}

/* 
 * Cleanup - unregister the appropriate file from /proc 
 */
void cleanup_module()
{
    unregister_chrdev(MAJOR_NUM, DEVICE_NAME);

#if 0
    int ret;
    /* 
     * Unregister the device 
     */
    ret = unregister_chrdev(MAJOR_NUM, DEVICE_NAME);
    /* 
     * If there's an error, report it 
     */
    if (ret < 0)
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: unregister_chrdev: %d\n", ret);
#endif
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify fops.read prototype and add your own arguments. It is a standard predefined character driver's interface which cannot be changed. Refer http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch03.html for proper understanding of character driver. Most of the functions provided through fops need to follow standard input and output behaviors, except ioctl(). You can use ioctl() of character drivers to do special operations like your's. http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch05.html#t1